# Are larger large cardinals less expressible?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

First note to the following well known theorems:‎‎

**Theorem (1):** ‎The ‎notion ‎of ‎"‎$‎‎x$ ‎is a strongly inaccessible cardinal‎" ‎is ‎first ‎order ‎expressible ‎and ‎‎$‎‎\Pi_{1}$‎.

**Theorem (2):**‎‎ ‎The ‎notion ‎of ‎"‎$‎‎x$ is a measurable cardinal‎" ‎is ‎first ‎order ‎expressible ‎but ‎not ‎‎$‎‎‎\Pi‎_{1}$‎.‎

**Theorem (3):** ‎The ‎notion ‎of ‎"‎$‎‎x$ is a Reinhardt cardinal‎" ‎is ‎not ‎first order expressible.‎ 
‎

Now there are some questions here:‎
‎

**Question (1):** ‎Are ‎larger ‎large ‎cardinals ‎more ‎complicated ‎in ‎first ‎order ‎expressibilty? ‎Is ‎there ‎any ‎exception?‎
‎

**Question (2):** ‎Is ‎there a‎ ‎non ‎first ‎orde‎r expressible large cardinal weaker than Reindhardt cardinal?‎
‎

**Question (3):** ‎What ‎is ‎the ‎largest $‎‎\Pi_{1}$ - ‎expressible ‎large ‎cardinal? ‎For ‎example the notions of being a ‎Mahlo ‎or ‎weakly ‎compact ‎cardinal ‎are ‎first ‎order ‎expressible ‎and‎ $‎‎\Pi_{1}$.

Comment: Being weakly compact is not $\Pi_1$.  There are transitive models $M \subseteq N$ where $\kappa$ is weakly compact in $N$ but not in $M$.  It is a $\Pi_2$ property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For question (1), there are many exceptions. For example, being [superstrong](http://cantorsattic.info/Superstrong#Superstrong_cardinal) is $\Sigma_2$ expressible, since it is witnessed inside a sufficiently large $V_\theta$, but this is stronger than strong in consistency strength, and being strong is $\Pi_3$. Similarly, being supercompact up to an inaccessible is $\Sigma_2$, but stronger than supercompact in strength, while being supercompact is $\Pi_3$. One can make many similar examples of very strong $\Sigma_2$ properties, by asserting that a strong $\Pi_3$ property holds up to an inaccessible cardinal. This reduces the complexity of the assertion, but is stronger consistency-wise.

For question (2), I would suggest [Vopěnka's principle](http://cantorsattic.info/Vopenka) as a commonly considered large cardinal concept that, if consistent, is not first-order expressible as a single assertion in the language of set theory. This axiom is typically formulated in second-order theories such as GBC.

Comment: Thanks for your elegant answers. What about question (3)?

Comment: I suppose one could take a look through Cantor's upper attic http://cantorsattic.info/Upper_attic. It seems that $\Pi_1$ doesn't get you very far past Mahloness. Of course, you can get to hyper-Mahlo and somewhat beyond, but I'm not sure that anything larger is $\Pi_1$. Meanwhile, consistency assertions are $\Pi^0_1$, such as $\text{Con}(\text{ZFC}+\text{proper class of supercompact cardinals})$, and these can have very high consistency strength. So if these count as "large cardinal properties", then we shouldn't expect a largest one.

Comment: So there is no direct relevance between largeness of a large cardinal and its first order expressibility. Do you have any information about this kind of relevance in a different sense?

Comment: I don't know if you'd count this as a large cardinal, but a very strong $\Pi_1$ property of $\kappa$ is there are stationary many huge cardinals below $\kappa$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, is that really $\Pi_1$? It looks at least $\Pi_2$ to me, since to say that $\delta$ is huge is $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\Pi^1_1$. Witnessing hugeness measures can be found in $V_\kappa$.

Comment: I agree with that, but I take the question to be about $\Pi_1$ in $V$, rather than $\Pi^1_1$ over $V_\kappa$.